# How to include the module name in magento2

Tags: magento2, getmodel

Is anyone knows how to load the model in magento2?

What we need to do in magento2 to translate the below line in Magento2

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public function __construct(
    ..
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    ..
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
}
```

and then

```
$this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Resource\Order\Invoice\Collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()))
```

OR

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Resource\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory $invoiceCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->_invoiceCollectionFactory = $invoiceCollectionFactory;
}
```

and then

```
$this->_invoiceCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also instantiate an object inline (without declaring it in a constructor) with the code:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $om */
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Resource\Order\Invoice\Collection $invoices */
$invoices = $om->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Resource\Order\Invoice\Collection');
```